# Removing Encryption from Android Backup

Tags: encryption

I made a backup of my android using twrp recovery, at that time I had setup PIN as password in the device. After that, i installed some other custom OS, but later thought of switching to it, everything goes well, except it asks for password, and when i enter the same PIN I had setup before, it says incorrect password, is there any way to remove that PIN from the backup itself?? Or removing the PIN after restoring the backup? I don't want to lose my data as well. My mobile is MI A1. Any solutions to it??

Comment: The latter might be possible, see our [locked-out tag-wiki](/tags/locked-out/info) and the questions using that tag.